# Set default value to a textarea (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I'm using PHP with AngularJS and I want to set the default value to the textarea.

However, I do not want to use `ng-init="textarea = ''"` because the data that I want to populate is quite large. I do not want to use AJAX either because that adds another request to the server.

Is there a way I can set the value with PHP directly like

```
<textarea ng-model="textarea"><?php echo $data ?></textarea>
```

Doing this shows nothing because Angular wants me to use a model to set the value.

**Current HTML**

```
<textarea ng-model="textarea" class="textarea"></textarea>
```

**Current AngularJS & JQuery**

```
$scope.jqta = $('.textarea');

$.get("/fetch", function(response) {
     $scope.jqta.text(response);
});
```

Comment: Can you get away with using `$scope.textarea = <?php echo $data ?>` in your AngularJS controller to init the value. You can't have multiline strings in JS so you'll have to replace all the newlines with '\n' so they still display correctly. I had this problem in python and did `val.replace('\n', '\\n')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HTML:

```
<textarea ng-model="textarea" class="textarea">Default value</textarea>
```

If that doesn't work:

```
$scope.textarea = 'Default value';
```

Comment: tried this it shows nothing because angular wants me to use the ng-model

Comment: $scope.textarea = 'this will have to be in a js file'. im trying to set it directly onto the php file.

Comment: @Moe Why's that? You should try your best to separate languages into separate files. Writing code inline is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: in the situation i am in is because the data is massive not just 1 line this is why i was trying to make it so it sets it via php.

Comment: @Moe That is *more* reason to separate things - you should have large strings of text in a database. If you do, and you're getting from the database using PHP, then check this example of how to set the `ng-model` value using a PHP variable: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26694/

Comment: @Moe PS: That above JSFiddle doesn't work because JSFiddle.net doesn't support PHP, but it will work on a PHP page. Note that I've used `json_decode()` as an example, if you were returning JSON. Just `echo $string` otherwise.

Comment: @Moe No worries, get back to me if it works. Remember to accept if it helped :)